# How to make a cluster of images aligned to the center in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So, I have a group of images arranged in a circle, and I'm trying to get them to stay in one place, regardless of how the screen is resized. The images are a series of petals arranged like a flower, and at first I had each petal placed by using absolute positioning and pixels away from the edges.  However, when I resize the image, the petals would all move to the left or right.
Then I placed the petals using percentage away from the edges.  Now each individual petal moves away from the center or towards the center.
I tried to create a div to keep the image as a whole clustered and positioned, but I haven't had any luck with that.
Any advice on how I can keep the petals in place?
Here's what the petal code looks like:

```
basics {
position: absolute;
left: 47.5%;
right: 52.5%;
}
```

there are twelve petals, each with a slightly different position.  Does anyone know how I can keep them in one place on the screen?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Laura. Did my answer help you? Would you mind marking it as accepted if it did? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way out would be to create a block with a position absolute, and position the images inside with their own absolute positioning. This would force the images to base their current position on the block itself.

Does that make sense?

Here's the HTML and CSS:

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g90gbdrp/1/

```css
  div {
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    top: calc(50% - 100px);
  }
  
  img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  #one {
    top: -2em;
    left: -2em;
  }
  
  #two {
    top: -2em;
    right: -2em;
  }
  
  #three {
    bottom: -2em;
    left: -2em;
  }
  
  #four {
    bottom: -2em;
    right: -2em;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/cat_PNG1631.png" id="one" />
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/cat_PNG1631.png" id="two" />
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/cat_PNG1631.png" id="three" />
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/cat_PNG1631.png" id="four" />
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help at all?  The petals aren't showing up, but if you resize the field, you'll see they move.  I want to keep them in a circle shape  https://jsfiddle.net/OpheliaCyanide/r4379e29/

Comment: Yeah that helps a lot. I've edited it and simple added a wrapping `div` and with some basic styling. https://jsfiddle.net/r4379e29/2/

Comment: So, my issue with that is that is that, when I resize the page, it doesn't stay in the center.  This means when I change computers, the flower might be way off to the side.  I need the flower to stay in the center.

Comment: That's easy. The wrapper already has a `position: absolute;` so you can move `top` and `left` by 50% minus half of the width/height. checkout this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/r4379e29/4/

Comment: oh my gosh, it worked!  You are literally a god send, thank you so much!!